# how can I load data from sqlite3 database to UITable directly as application loaded?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, uitableview

hello
I have stored some data in sqlite3 database, and i am retrieving it, and saving to an array but now I want to show the data as the application loads in the UITable, how can I do it ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the data retrieved in an array, you can use reloadData method to reload the data in the your table view. For ex.

```
[yourTableView reloadData];
```

Make sure, the  `numberOfRowsInSection..` return the array count, like,

`[arrData count];`

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath..` delegate method, display the data from the array..like

`cell.textLabel.text = [arrData objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];`

I hope, it helps

Comment: this is what I am doing, but what if I just want to see previous data in UITableView which is in sqlite database? u can say as I click the UITableView class and I can see the data?

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not able to understand your exact requirement. Please clarify it in. What do you mean by "I just want to see previous data in UITableView which is in sqlite database?"?

Comment: at some extend your answer is right, but I have to call select method, which will take data form sqlite3 database, and then I will assign that data to my NSMutableString, index by index, and display on UITableView.